# Pandas DateOffset to duplicate other columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, offset

I have a dataframe with loans (loan_id) given to accounts (account_id), their duration (loan_duration) and the monthly payment for the loan (monthly_loan_payment).

[image]

Ultimately, I want to extract the sum of monthly payments for each month for each client. In order to get there I am trying to extract a data frame that gives me the account_id, the month and the monthly payment for each loan and each of the months of its duration. Say a loan was issued in 07/1993, with a monthly payment of 1000$ and has a duration of 12 months, I would like to return a row with the account_id, loan_id and monthly payment information for each of the 12 months of the loan duration. The same for every single loan in the df.

[image]

I tried `df.groupby('account_id').apply(lambda x: x['date'] + pd.DateOffset(months = x['loan_duration'], axis=1)['monthly_payment']`  but did not succeed. How can I do a date offset on each row, while duplicating the content of the other columns at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `pd.date_range` for every loan and use `df.explode` to get all the individual payments.

```
# sample data
# please always provide a callable line of code with your data
# you can get it with `df.head().to_dict('split')`
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'account_id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3],
    'loan_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'date': ['1993-07-01', '1993-08-01', '1993-09-01', '1993-09-01', '1993-09-01'],
    'loan_duration_months': [12, 6, 5, 10, 10],
    'monthly_payment': [1000, 500, 1000, 1000, 1000]
})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['payment_date'] = [
    pd.date_range(start, periods=duration, freq='M')
    for start, duration in zip(df['date'], df['loan_duration_months'])
]
df = df.explode('payment_date', ignore_index=True)
```

Output

```
    account_id  loan_id       date  loan_duration_months  monthly_payment payment_date
0            1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1993-07-31
1            1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1993-08-31
2            1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1993-09-30
3            1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1993-10-31
4            1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1993-11-30
5            1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1993-12-31
6            1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1994-01-31
7            1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1994-02-28
8            1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1994-03-31
9            1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1994-04-30
10           1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1994-05-31
11           1        1 1993-07-01                    12             1000   1994-06-30
12           1        2 1993-08-01                     6              500   1993-08-31
13           1        2 1993-08-01                     6              500   1993-09-30
14           1        2 1993-08-01                     6              500   1993-10-31
15           1        2 1993-08-01                     6              500   1993-11-30
16           1        2 1993-08-01                     6              500   1993-12-31
17           1        2 1993-08-01                     6              500   1994-01-31
18           2        3 1993-09-01                     5             1000   1993-09-30
19           2        3 1993-09-01                     5             1000   1993-10-31
20           2        3 1993-09-01                     5             1000   1993-11-30
21           2        3 1993-09-01                     5             1000   1993-12-31
22           2        3 1993-09-01                     5             1000   1994-01-31
23           3        4 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1993-09-30
24           3        4 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1993-10-31
25           3        4 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1993-11-30
26           3        4 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1993-12-31
27           3        4 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-01-31
28           3        4 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-02-28
29           3        4 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-03-31
30           3        4 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-04-30
31           3        4 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-05-31
32           3        4 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-06-30
33           3        5 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1993-09-30
34           3        5 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1993-10-31
35           3        5 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1993-11-30
36           3        5 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1993-12-31
37           3        5 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-01-31
38           3        5 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-02-28
39           3        5 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-03-31
40           3        5 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-04-30
41           3        5 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-05-31
42           3        5 1993-09-01                    10             1000   1994-06-30
```

Comment: Hey Richie, thanks so much for the reply. It works perfectly! Also thanks for the tipp about the callable line of code. Will do next time!